# How do I set columnNames for a dataGridView bound to a List<T>?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, datagridview, datasource

As shown below I have created a List of equip.I would like to have the column names more descriptive - is there an attribute that I can use in the equip.properties?

```
DataGridView.Datasource = EquipList;

List<equip> EquipList = new List<equip>();

public class equip
{
 public int EquipID {get;set;}
 public string EquipName {get;set;}
}
```

Okay, maybe I didn't explain myself properly...I am hoping that that there is an attribute that could be applied like....

```
[Alis("name I would like to see in the gridview")]
public int EquipID {get;set;}
```

if not I'll just stick with the old tired ways

Later on that same morning....

I got it!

```
 using System.ComponentModel;

[DisplayName("the nice name")]
 public int EquipID {get;set;}
```

Comment: dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Equipment Name"; This should work after the binding has been applied. WinForms?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This works..

```
using System.ComponentModel;

List<equip> EquipList = new List<equip>();

DataGridView.Datasource = EquipList;
```

below:the first two properties in the class will be displayed with
with their new names, the third property will not display as per the
Browsable attribute.

```
public class equip
  {
   [DisplayName("Equipment ID")]
   public int EquipID {get;set;}

   [DisplayName("Equipment Name")]
   public string EquipName {get;set;}

   [Browsable(false)]
   public int recordId {get; private set;}
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dt = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
dt.DataPropertyName = "EquipName"; //Property to bind.
dt.HeaderText = "Name";
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dt);
```

You can achieve this easily with Designer.

Comment: thats just so long and laborious

Comment: @Brad This is the better answer anyways. You can add columns with 1 simple line: `dataGridView1.Columns.Add("", "EquipID");` and `dataGridView1.Columns.Add("", "EquipName");`