# C# Datatable Grid Calculation

Tags: c#, matrix, datatable

I have been trying to build a simple grid calculation in a C# Winform DataTable where a user inputs the starting value, ending value, spread starting value and spread ending value (in the below code I just hard coded the values). From there, the table builds a matrix of calculated values.

For example (initial structure):

Price    A  B   C   D

1
2
3
4

Calculated values:

1 - A,  1 - B,  1 - C,  1 - D,
2 - A,  2 - B,  2 - C,  2 - D,
3 - A,  3 - B,  3 - C,  3 - D,
4 - A,  4 - B,  4 - C,  4 - D,

The below grid was my first attempt at building a calculated grid - what would be a better solution to this than the below?:

```
static DataTable GetCalcGrid()
        {

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Clear();
            DataColumn column;
            DataRow row;

            try
            {
                //double minValue = (double)startingPrice.Value;
                double minValue = 1;
                //double maxValue = (double)endingPrice.Value;
                double maxValue = 2;
                //double incrementValue = (double)incrementPrice.Value;
                double incrementValue = .25;

                //double minSpreadValue = (double)spreadRangeLow.Value;
                double minSpreadValue = -.50;
                //double maxSpreadValue = (double)spreadRangeHigh.Value;
                double maxSpreadValue = .50;
                //double incrementSpreadValue = (double)spreadIncrement.Value;
                double incrementSpreadValue = .25;

                column = new DataColumn();
                column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
                column.ColumnName = "N*";
                column.AutoIncrement = true;
                column.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
                column.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
                table.Columns.Add(column);

                column = new DataColumn();
                column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double");
                column.ColumnName = "Price";
                table.Columns.Add(column);

                for (double x = minSpreadValue; x < maxSpreadValue + incrementSpreadValue; x += incrementSpreadValue)
                {
                    double value;
                    value = x;

                    column = new DataColumn();
                    column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Double");
                    column.ColumnName = value.ToString("0.000");
                    table.Columns.Add(column);
                    table.Columns[value.ToString("0.000")].Expression = "(([Price] + (" + value + ")))";
                    //table.Columns[value.ToString("0.000")].Expression = " " + OP.black("C",4,Convert.ToDouble("(([Price] + (" + value + ")))"),.32,15,365,.003,1).ToString() + " ";
                }

                for (double i = minValue; i < maxValue + incrementValue; i += incrementValue)
                {
                    row = table.NewRow();
                    row["Price"] = i;
                    table.Rows.Add(row);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show("! " + ex); }
            finally { }

            return table;
        }

    private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = GetCalcGrid();
    }
```

Comment: There does not appear to be a question here.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for when you say you want a better solution?

Comment: @Matt - the way I built this is by using Expressions. I would imagine there is a faster and better coding solution than this. Maybe a Multidimensional Arrays is a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public class Matrix : List<MatrixEntry>
    {
    }

    public class MatrixEntry
    {
        public double Price { get; private set; }

        public double Value1
        {
            get { return (Price - 0.5); }
        }

        public double Value2
        {
            get { return (Price - 0.25); }
        }

        public double Value3
        {
            get { return Price; }
        }

        public double Value4
        {
            get { return (Price + 0.25); }
        }

        public double Value5
        {
            get { return (Price + 0.5); }
        }

        public MatrixEntry(double price)
        {
            Price = price;
        }
    }

static Matrix GetMatrixCalcGrid()
        {
            var matrix = new Matrix();

            try
            {
                double minValue = 1;
                double maxValue = 2;
                double incrementValue = .25;

                for (double i = minValue; i < maxValue + incrementValue; i += incrementValue)
                {
                    var entry = new MatrixEntry(i);
                    matrix.Add(entry);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine("! " + ex); }
            finally { }

            return matrix;
        }
```

Is this what you're looking for?

NOTE: I have obviously hard coded the calculations.. but you can add some extra properties to store the user inputs and modify the properties to return the correct values. The main point of my example is that I think it is more efficient than using a DataTable.

Comment: Yes, this is a much better solution than my previous code. However, this returns a static value/name (for example 'Value4') to the column, rather than a dynamic value/name. Appreciate the help!

Comment: You're welcome. For the column names, you can use a [DisplayName] attribute. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551418/how-do-i-set-columnnames-for-a-datagridview-bound-to-a-listt

Comment: Oh I just realized you wanted dynamic.. in that case, you can also change the DataGridView column names programatically. Example: `dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "My Column Name";`