# How to set headers for columns in DataGridView, where data is populated from a sql query

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I have the following code working, I just want to display my own column names for each column rather than the ones in the database.

Is there any way I can do that?

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "total_registration";
cmd.Connection = con;
using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con))
{        
    DataTable t = new DataTable();
    a.Fill(t);

    grid.DataSource = t;
}
```

Comment: Is this what you needed? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551418/how-do-i-set-columnnames-for-a-datagridview-bound-to-a-listt

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas No this doesnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after binding datasource set column header text explicitly using the DataGridView.Columns[].HeaderText property:

```
grid.DataSource = t;
grid.Columns["ID"].HeaderText  = "Identifier";
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there ist a special SQL-Statement for this.

For example you have a table in your DB with the following columns 
ID, Name, Age
and you want to name them like the following
Identification LastName AgeYear

you could use the following sql-statement:

> SELECT ID as Identification, Name as LastName, Age as AgeYear  FROM db;

Hope it help.